# How to process data from query in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server, sqlsrv

I wanted to display data from SQL Server database in my html page. I already wrote a code that get data in PHP :

```
<?php 
      $serverName = "srv\SQLEXPRESS";
      $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "PROFACE", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"pwd");
      $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

      if($conn) {
        echo "Connexion OK <br/>";
      } else {
        echo "La connexion NOK <br/>";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }

      $sql = "SELECT * 
              FROM PROFACE.dbo.SuiviProduction 
              WHERE Time_Stamp >= DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)
              AND DATEPART(HOUR,Time_Stamp) = DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())-2";

      $params = array(1, "some data");
      $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
      if($stmt == false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      } else {
        $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        sqlsrv_close($stmt);
      }
     ?>
```

Then I wanted to display the result of the query, so I wrote :

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
         //echo "{$key} => {$value}";
          print_r($data);
}
```

What I have is this following :

`Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-11-13 08:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [Time_Stamp] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-11-13 08:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) [1] => 237 [Time_Stamp_ms] => 237 [2] => 2227 [CompteurTotalLot] => 2227 [3] => 2001 [CompteurBonnesLot] => 2001 [4] => 10 [CompteurRebutsLot] => 10 [5] => 3120227 [CompteurTotalisateur] => 3120227 )`

How can I process this data in order to have data in a json format?

Comment: Well, did you check the value of `$key` and `$value`? That should give you the idea on how to get the values

Comment: question is how do you want it to process it
Whats the end goal?

Comment: Is it possible to sort it in json file ?

Comment: What JSON file? Sort it how?

Comment: The result that I have (Array [0] ...), can I put it in a json file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the following:

- Use `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` with `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` or `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC` as `$fetchType` parameter to retrieve only one value per column (the default value is `SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH`)
- PHP Driver for SQL Server may return PHP DateTime objects as strings or as DateTime objects by setting the `'ReturnDatesAsStrings'` option in the connection string or at the statement level (the default value is `false`). If you want a text output, use this option in `sqlsrv_query()` call or format your PHP DateTime objects using PHP `DateTime::format()` method.
- Use `sqlsrv_close()` to close the connection, not the statement.

The next examples may help to get the expected results:

JSON flle:

```
<?php 
    // Connection
    $serverName = "srv\SQLEXPRESS";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "PROFACE", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"pwd");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connexion OK <br/>";
    } else {
        echo "La connexion NOK <br/>";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    // Statement
    $sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM PROFACE.dbo.SuiviProduction 
        WHERE 
            Time_Stamp >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND 
            DATEPART(HOUR, Time_Stamp) = DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) - 2
    ";
    $params = array(1, "some data");
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    // JSON Output
    $output = array();
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    file_put_contents('filename.txt', json_encode($output));

    // End
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

HTML output:

```
<?php 
    // Connection
    $serverName = "srv\SQLEXPRESS";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "PROFACE", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"pwd");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connexion OK <br/>";
    } else {
        echo "La connexion NOK <br/>";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    // Statement
    $sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM PROFACE.dbo.SuiviProduction 
        WHERE 
            Time_Stamp >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND 
            DATEPART(HOUR, Time_Stamp) = DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) - 2
    ";
    $params = array(1, "some data");
    $options = array('ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    // HTML output
    echo '<table>';
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }   
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

    // End
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for help ! I try the two options, the JSON output works fine but the HTML output doesn't display anything.

Comment: @MissKnacki Execute both scripts separately. Thanks.

Comment: In different file?

Comment: @MissKnacki Yes. If you fetch the data with `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` to generate the JSON output, the HTML output will be empty, because the data is already fetched. Execute first or second script and choose which one is the more appropriate.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand better now ! And it works fine. Thank you very much :)